# How to filter data in an array with a set of criteria from $_GET

Tags: php

I'm having trouble filtering an array.

I'm passing a set of features in the URL, and I want to match items from my array that have all the specified features. As soon as I remove a parameter from the URL the code falls apart as I'm using `$_GET` to filter. I've gone ahead and created an array for debugging purposes. I also provided the the get parameters as a comment in the code. Can some one please help me out here? Please feel free to copy the code to your IDE.

The following is my code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

//  Created a static array for you guys for debugging 
//  page.php?pool=1&beach=1&concierge=1   put this url path at the end of the url so you can get the data im seeing
$htls=array(
    array("HotelName"=>"M Beach Hotel","minprice"=>264,"CountryCode"=>"US",'feature'=>array("type"=>"hotel","pool"=>1,"beach"=>1,'concierge'=>0)), array("HotelName"=>"Hilton","minprice"=>73,"CountryCode"=>"US",'feature'=>array("type"=>"hotel","pool"=>1,"beach"=>0,'concierge'=>1)),
    array("HotelName"=>"Fontainebleau","minprice"=>375,"CountryCode"=>"US",'feature'=>array("type"=>"resort","pool"=>1,"beach"=>1,'concierge'=>1)),
    array("HotelName"=>"Woodlow Inn","minprice"=>40,"CountryCode"=>"US",'feature'=>array("type"=>"inn","pool"=>0,"beach"=>0,'concierge'=>0)),
    array("HotelName"=>"El cabanna","minprice"=>73,"CountryCode"=>"US",'feature'=>array("type"=>"resort","pool"=>1,"beach"=>1,'concierge'=>1)),
    array("HotelName"=>"James south beach","minprice"=>73,"CountryCode"=>"US",'feature'=>array("type"=>"hotel","pool"=>0,"beach"=>1,'concierge'=>0)),
);

foreach($htls as $key1 => $val ){

    foreach($val['feature'] as $key => $val2){   

        //   Here's where I start to get lost soon as a parameter is not in the url for example ?pool=1 the code falls apart.
        if ($_GET['pool']==1 && $val['feature']['pool']==1  and  $_GET['beach']==1 && $val['feature']['beach']==1 and  $_GET['concierge']==1 && $val['feature']['concierge']==1) 
        {
            echo $key.'- '.$val2.' - '.$val['feature']['pool'].' - '.$val['HotelName'].'<br>';         

        }   
        break;  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: @Dezza not a duplicate this has nothing to do with my post. The guy is talking about an undefined var. I'm having issues with filtering my array. I searched long and hard and can't find anything relevant for my exact need. I tried a couple  examples ,but couldn't get them to work.

Comment: @LogicalNonsense I added a bit more explanation to your question. Please feel free to re-edit or roll back if you disagree with it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thank you so much you're a lifesaver. I wish I could up-vote your answer again.You did an excellent job explaining the code.Exactly what I was looking for(:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to match items from your hotels array that have all of the set of features included in the query string, you can filter your array using `array_diff_assoc` to compare the array of features in `$_GET` with the array of features of the hotel record.

```
$filtered = array_filter($htls, function($hotel) {
    return !array_diff_assoc($_GET, $hotel['feature']);
});
```

[`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) will return an array of any key/value pairs in `$_GET` that aren't included in `$hotel['feature']`. Negating it with `!` will [implicitly cast it to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), so the callback will return `true` if it's empty and `false` if it's not.

This just does the filtering. After they're filtered you can iterate `$filtered` and output them however you need to.

If there are other parameters besides the filters in `$_GET`, you can rename your filter controls with an array format to group them together, so you can refer to `$_GET['filters']` instead of just `$_GET`. I'm guessing these values may come from checkboxes, so it would be like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[pool]" value="1">
```

[Executable example at 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/Ps37G)